# Compiling Sass SCSS on-the-fly in Cloud9 IDE

Tags: cloud9-ide

Cloud9 IDE seems to support formatting/coloring for SCSS files, but there does not appear to be a setting in the preferences for SCSS files to be automatically processed into CSS.

The only way I have found to achieve this is add the SCSS gem, then leave `scss --watch` running in the background.

Are there any better ways than this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enable this via the Run menu:
[image]